# Connect with Powershell console to runspace embedded in my app

Tags: .net, powershell, .net-4.0

I'm trying to embed PS in my .NET app to make part of object model easily discoverable and have the ability to navigate it. It is easy to create runspace, prompt user for some script as plain string, run the script in the runspace and output something to the user. But in that way it lacks interactivity - user doesn't get auto-completion, IntelliSense, tooltips etc, thus he is required to issue `Get-Members` constantly just to know what he can do with given objects.

As I understand interactivity is provided by `PSHost` thing.
Is it possible to go without implementing it manually in the application, but rather expose embedded runspace somehow, so I can connect to it with PowerGUI for example? `Enter-PSSession` or something alike.

Comment: You could use `ConsoleShell`.  
See [this related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17086643/619493).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure you will have to implement your own tab completion as that's done by the PowerShell Host.

Comment: Sort of.  The bulk of the business logic is in TabExpanion() [or TabExpansion2() in v3].  You just need to provide the passing of user input and display of output to the user in your host.